# oninput event fires once. May also have a scope issue

Tags: javascript, html

Good Evening,

I am having trouble with modifying the date value in my test object. The oninput event seems to only fire once when the document is loaded. The oninput event does not seem to fire when the date is changed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>

    var TestObj = new function(){

        this.date = "2014-01-01";

        this.LoadMenu = function() {
            var newDateInput = document.createElement('input');
            newDateInput.type = "date";
            newDateInput.value = this.date;
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newDateInput);
            newDateInput.oninput = this.updateDate(newDateInput.value);
        };

        this.updateDate =   function (newDate){
            this.date = newDate;
            alert(this.date);
            document.getElementById("outputBox").innerHtml = this.date;
        };
    };

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="TestObj.LoadMenu();">
<div id="container">
<div id="outputBox">Test</div>
</div>
```

Chrome: 34.0.1847.116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because of the way you are trying to associate the handler function of your event, in your code you have:

```
newDateInput.oninput = this.updateDate(newDateInput.value);
```

but what you might want is:

```
newDateInput.oninput = this.updateDate;
```

Also, if you want this to work properly you might want to declare the `newDateInput` in the outer scope (in the scope of the "class").

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
var TestObj = new function(){

    this.date = "2014-01-01";
    var newDateInput;

    this.LoadMenu = function() {
        newDateInput = document.createElement('input');
        newDateInput.type = "date";
        newDateInput.value = this.date;
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newDateInput);
        newDateInput.oninput = this.updateDate;
    };

    this.updateDate =   function (event){
        this.date = newDateInput.value;
        alert(this.date);
        document.getElementById("outputBox").innerHTML = this.date + '';
    };
};
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I wanted to create the var newDateInput within the LoadMenu function, how would I go about passing the newDateInput information to the updateDate function without declaring newDateInput in the outer scope?